# How to add an action to a material?

Tags: animation, materials

I'm trying to create a traffic light in blender, I assigned all the needed materials(3 colors), I created animation for each color, but in the Dope Sheet Window, when I choose Action Editor there is no any actions.  And when I exported the object as fbx and imported to Unity the animated colors doesn't work.

Any solutions? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about material action support in unity, however I am pretty sure you can use a UV animation,

Just move the lights face to a copy of the face lit up?

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/19848/making-textures-scroll-animate-textures.html

This way you just need the 'lit up' texture face in the uv sheet for each color.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I will check it.

Comment: What I have done in blender I add animation to emit of the material, that means it is brighter for 10 seconds and after the emit = 0